# When hitting min-wdith viewport scaling behaves differently in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

Given the following code:

```
body, html {min-width: 300px}
//and 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

In Chrome, if I shrink the responsive view to 200px, starting from 300px, it will scale down as the browser width gets smaller.

In Firefox, if I shrink the responsive view to 200px, all the components on the page will stay at min-width 300px, they do not scale down any further, but a page scrollbar will come out.

I want the Chrome behavior, not the Firefox behavior. What css do I need to set to make sure of that in Firefox?
[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot that compares Chrome and Firefox? I'm having trouble visualizing what you're describing.

Comment: @Dai made a picture to indicate it.

Comment: If this Bug Report is the same issue (I only skimmed it), then Firefox doesn't support it (yet): https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1213951 - but as a workaround, why not make your site work with a 200px viewport width? BTW, no actual mobile web-browser has a viewport width of 200px - I think the smallest-ever was `320px` (in the original iPhone), so why both trying to support 200px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug with Chrome, it should be like that of Firefox.
When you set a min-width on an element, that will be the minimum width of the element, regardless of anything; this is according to the spec.
The following proves that the Firefox behavior is present in Chrome, too, in non-responsive mode.

```
<style>html,body{margin:0}</style>
<div style="width:150%;height:50px;background:lightgray"></div>
```

I’m not sure what you’re trying to achieve with `min-width: 300px` on the whole page when it’d be the device-width, but as @Dai said, there is no device (except an iframe pixel) where the viewport is any smaller than 320px. It is normal and funny for a website’s CSS and text to completely break when at 200px.

**Remove the code. You only need to worry about devices >= 320px in width.**

Comment: Arguably, Chrome's behaviour isn't a "bug": I believe there's nothing against any spec allowing the layout-engine to downscale the rendered view to fit the viewport.

Comment: @Dai I think it's undefined behavior, but Chrome does it differently in non-responsive mode as seen in my code.